# um.. What is AgensGraph?

Tags: definition, agens-graph

I heard about *AgensGraph*, but I wonder exactly what it is.

If you know someone, please let me know.

Comment: From the tag description: *"AgensGraph is a graph database based-on PostgreSQL. It is a robust and fully-featured graph database. AgensGraph can store graph data with relational data. And it also process Cypher and SQL queries and two query languages can be integrated in a single query."*

Answer (score 1):

I got "What is AgensGraph" from AgensGraph documentation, which you can find this document from a following link: http://bitnine.net/support/documents_backup/quick-start-guide-html/

> Agens Graph is a new generation multi-model graph database for the modern complex data environment. Agens Graph is a multi-model database, which supports relational and graph data model at the same time. It enables developers to integrate the legacy relational data model and the nobel graph data model in one database. Agens Graph supports Ansi-SQL and Open Cypher (http://www.opencypher.org). SQL query and Cypher query can be integrated into a single query in Agens Graph.
>
> Agens Graph is based on powerful PostgreSQL RDBMS, so it is very robust, fully-featured and ready to enterprise use. It is optimzied for handling complex connected graph data but at the same time, it provides a plenty of powerful database features essential to the enterprise database environment, like ACID transaction, multi version concurrency control, stored procedure, trigger, constraint, sophistrated monitoring and flexible data model (JSON). Moreover, Agens Graph can leverage the rich eco-systems of PostgreSQL and can be extended with many outstanding external modules, like PostGIS.